# Deep Clone tables from Remote Oracle to Local Oracle XE with schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My current task involves deep cloning [table, index, sequence] a set of tables (not all of them are in the same schema) from a remote (Prod) Oracle DB to my local (Dev) XE Db (including data), and - if possible - even having it all be one script or file I can execute (if need be, I can hope they accept a compiled program).

I knew of `create table <name> as select * from <name>@<link>` and the equivalent insert, which is probably the best for copying the data, but not definition

I've searched around and stumbled across `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` which helped a bit, but I haven't figured out how to connect to the remote database using it, and also haven't found out how to get the tables from the other schemas.

I have a total of 3 schemas (the main one for my application (we'll call "MY", the company's base data (we'll call "COMP" and a related application of a colleague (we'll call "COLL"))

I've tried the script from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm), which looked promising, but as I said, I haven't figured out how to connect to remote and the different schemas (the company is the hardest one, as I don't know if I can log into it, and only have select permission

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', table_name, owner)
FROM all_tables WHERE owner = UPPER('&1');
```

When I tried the get_ddl with a different owner, the sql developer gave me the error:

> "Object %s of type TABLE in schema %s not found" where the first %s is
> the first table in the (second %s) schema (COMP)

Comment: Why not use the export/import utilites (expdp/impdp)?  https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump.html#GUID-501A9908-BCC5-434C-8853-9A6096766B5A

Comment: Trying to replicate dbms_metadata yourself is going to be a truly enormous task that you'll need to revisit with every Oracle release. How confident are you that you can code for the complete [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html) syntax? I'm not sure I'd attempt it.

Answer (score 0):

Dbms_metadata is good option. But for using it with dblink you have to write more code.
First your remote user (dblinku user) should have select_catalog_role.

Below example is not complete solution and it should work only for object per request.  For more details got to dbms_metadata manual.

```
Declare 
    h1      NUMBER;   
    table_name varchar2(100) :='table_name';
    from_schema varchar2(100) :='schema_name';
    db_link  varchar2(100) :='db_link_name';
    xml     CLOB;          
    begin
    h1 := DBMS_METADATA.OPEN('TABLE',network_link => db_link ); --open context with db link name. 
    DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h1,'NAME',table_name);
    DBMS_METADATA.SET_FILTER(h1,'SCHEMA',from_schema);
    xml := DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_CLOB(h1);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(h1);
    IF xml IS not NULL THEN 
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(xml);
      END IF;
    DBMS_METADATA.CLOSE(h1);
    end;
```